# Should the 'TPR of adaboost' be better than base classifiers'?

Tags: machine-learning, adaboost

There are two different base classifiers which produce true positive rate (TPR) values 99.46% and 91.79%. When I use these base classifiers in [adaboost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost), what should the new TPR be? Better than two of them? Better than one of them?

Comment: TPR=True Positive Rate